# Splash screen in OSX Cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm working on a Cocoa app in Xcode.

I would like to create a splash screen using a .png file as the image content in the splash screen.

I've accomplished the following:

- The splash screen is displayed for 2 seconds when the app is launched
- The splash screen is displayed at the center of the screen
- The splash screen can't be minimized, moved or re-sized by the user

From my class:

```
IBOutlet NSView *customView;
IBOutlet NSImageView *splashScreen;
IBOutlet NSWindow *splashWindow;
```

Here's what I have so far in awakeFromNib

```
NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(0,0,421,231);
splashScreen = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
[splashScreen setImageScaling:NSScaleToFit];
[splashScreen setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"splash.png"]];
[customView addSubview:splashScreen];

CGFloat xPos = NSWidth([[splashWindow screen] frame])/2 - NSWidth([splashWindow frame])/2;
CGFloat yPos = NSHeight([[splashWindow screen] frame])/2 - NSHeight([splashWindow frame])/2;
[splashWindow setFrame:NSMakeRect(xPos, yPos, NSWidth([splashWindow frame]), NSHeight([splashWindow frame])) display:YES];
```

And then in applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
sleep(2); /* Yeah. I know this is bad. No need to comment on that */
[splashWindow close];
```

Questions:

1. How do I bring the splash image to the front of every open window on the desktop?
2. The PNG is a rectangle but the tiny areas near the corners of the image should be transparent. However...the transparent spots just shows as white..How do I fix that?
3. How do I implement the feature where the image is closed if the user clicks on the image before it's closed automatically?
4. How do I set up a timer to close the window after 2-3 seconds? (NSTimer)

Comment: I really tried to answer it but there is a lot to explain here. it seems kinda broad to me ..

Comment: btw some advice: don't -- see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685062/how-to-show-a-splash-screen-during-launch-of-a-cocoa-app/686599#686599

Comment: I really tried to answer it but there is a lot to explain here. it seems kinda broad to me => I agree.  That's why I didn't bother yesterday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for:

1. use `zwindow level property of NSWindow` and make the splash window **floating**
2. make the window non opaque **(requires a borderless window)** so google for a tutorial on how to make such a window type
3. AND 4. sleep is actually preventing the things. for 3 you'd need a mouseDown on the image, for  4 a timer ==> both are events. events are NOT dispatched when you sleep the main thread. The NSRunLoop must be running. One way would be too have a `NSRunloop runUntilDate` call instead of the sleep

Comment: Thank you. Answers like yours is what makes this site worth visiting. I appreciate it. I'll try it out and post the final code when I'm done.

Comment: Something about running a runloop here seems off to me, though I'm not sure what. Rather than resorting to a runloop, I'd suggest calling `[splashWindow performSelector:@selector(close) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];`